# How to protect my files on external harddisk from being deleted

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-permissions

My brother and I share the same external hard disk the problem I have is how to protect my files from being deleted by him or any body else.
I want to make sure that the file can be viewed/copied but not cut/deleted. We both use different pc systems. This would help also when I give my hdd to someone else.

P.S. Dont suggest encryption softwares and other stuff (TrueCrypt etc.).

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't want us to suggest you to use encryption software, then what's left? Magic?

Comment: This can be done with the standard user permission system built within the operating system.  Of course an Administrator or Root users on ANY system can take ownership of the files

Comment: Instead of a regular old magnetic disk, use an optical disc (CD or DVD).  That way, he won’t be able to modify or delete the files.  Of course, neither will you.  And he will be able to delete the files by destroying the disc.  As the answers say, what you want is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done if you give the HDD away. Physical access to the device implies write access.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but encryption is the only way.  Dropbox sharing is a good idea for this sort of thing if you don't end up filling your drive though.

On the other hand, password-locked zip documents are a possibility... But deleting it is still possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you give him physical access then only solution against deletion is always having a backup at all times.